# Rolling restart of cloudfoundry application

Tags: deployment, cloud-foundry

I have cloudfoundry setup on mydev environment. We have an application 'Test' with 3 instances against it. When I do cf restart Test it restart all the 3 instances.

Is there a way by which I can restart 1 instance at a time. This will be highly useful for me when I need to update my service and don't want an outage in live environment.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question:

> Is there a way by which I can restart 1 instance at a time.

Yes, there is a way to restart just a single instance as documented here:
http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/restart-app-instance.html

`cf restart-app-instance APP_NAME INDEX`

In your case this would be:

```
cf restart-app-instance Test 0
cf restart-app-instance Test 1
cf restart-app-instance Test 2
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes this is what I am using now as we have upgraded our CF infra. Earlier this was not possible with the version we were using.

Answer (score 3):

If you update one at a time, you will have an inconsistent service running during the roll.  This may be okay in some situations, but another strategy you can use is a [blue-green deploy](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html).  There is even a `cf` CLI plugin called [autopilot](https://github.com/concourse/autopilot) that will orchestrate this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the strategy documentation link. Let me try that out

Comment: I generally agree with your point here, but there may be situations, where you want to restart an application without knowing the full deployment manifest / specifications.

Answer (score 0):

With Cloud Foundry cli v7, there is a rolling restart option, which will start a new instance, then stop an instance, until the number of new running nodes matches the number deployed.

```
cf restart APP-NAME --strategy rolling
```

See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/rolling-deploy.html. Scroll down to "Restart an app"